# C# - Application continues running in the background when closing it after an another form was opened

Tags: c#, forms

When I click on About, a new form opens and the main form hides. I have a close button on the About button, that **closes** the About form, and it shows up the Main form. However, when I close the main form with the 'X' close button on top, the Main form closes, but the process is still running in the background. Everything is okay when I dont click on the About button. It kills the process.

Comment: why are you closing the entire app when exiting the About form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Form2`, you need to bring up the existing `Form1 instance` rather than creating a new one (that's why closing this newly created `Form1` won't exit the application, as your old `Form1` instance is still hiding...).
So you could get reference passed when creating `aboutdialog`, and show that instead when closing `aboutdialog`:

Form1:

```
private void AboutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var aboutdialog = new Form2(this);
            aboutdialog.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Form2:

```
Form1 _parentform;
public Form2(Form1 parent)
        {
            _parentform=parent;
            InitializeComponent();
        }



private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _parentform.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "AboutButton_Click" method you hide the Form1. But when closing the About dialog, you do not show back the Form1, but create a new one. The original Form1 stays hidden and prevents your application from closing.

Comment: Oh. And can you tell me how can I fix this? Like how should I make it show again?

Comment: that's what i said in my comments originally: why are you closing down the application on the About form? it makes no sense...

Comment: I'd recommend to use user3420762' sample for that. If you don't like to hide the Form1 then pass the Form1 instance in the constructor to Form2, and then you'll have the original instance to do a Show on it.

Answer (score 0):

better to use showdialog.

```
private void AboutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var aboutdialog = new Form2();
    aboutdialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When form2 is closed a new instance of form1 is opened, instead of the original one. You could include a reference to Form1 inside of Form2, or use the default `Owner`of a form, by showing the dialog with Form1 as its owner:

```
aboutdialog.Show(this);
```

in the about...click

and closing

```
  private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Owner.Show(); 
            this.Close();
        }
```